# Logstash giving an error message which doesn't relate to configuration

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

So, I'm attempting to setup Logstash working with the logstash-forwarder, but I'm having some issues. It doesn't seem like lumberjack actually starts up and listens on port 5000 (checked with `netstat -anltp`) and an error message, which doesn't seem to relate to my configuration is dumped in to the logstash log.

My Config file

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/ssl/star_server_com.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/ssl/server.key"
    type => "somelogs"
 }
}
output {
  elasticsearch_http {
    host => "haproxy.server.com"
    password => "a0fe9d5dedwedfacd240a25b0"
    user => "90765547wfefwefwee429f"
  }
}
```

Output from --configtest

```
Using milestone 1 input plugin 'lumberjack'. This plugin should work, but would benefit from use by folks like you. Please let us know if you find bugs or have suggestions on how to improve this plugin.  For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2-modified/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
Using milestone 2 output plugin 'elasticsearch_http'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2-modified/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
```

Error messsage in /var/log/logstash/logstash.log

```
{
    : timestamp=>"2014-12-05T07:47:35.065000+0000",
    : message=>"Error parsing JSON",
    : json=>"{\"logstash\":{\"order\":0,\"template\":\"logstash-*\",\"settings\":{\"index.refresh_interval\":\"5s\"},\"mappings\":{\"_default_\":{\"dynamic_templates\":[{\"string_fields\":{\"mapping\":{\"index\":\"analyzed\",\"omit_norms\":true,\"type\":\"string\",\"fields\":{\"raw\":{\"index\":\"not_analyzed\",\"ignore_above\":256,\"type\":\"string\"}}},\"match_mapping_type\":\"string\",\"match\":\"*\"}}],\"properties\":{\"geoip\":{\"dynamic\":true,\"path\":\"full\",\"properties\":{\"location\":{\"type\":\"geo_point\"}},\"type\":\"object\"},\"@version\":{\"index\":\"not_analyzed\",\"type\":\"string\"}},\"_all\":{\"enabled\":true}}},\"aliases\":{}}}H",
    : results=>"",
    : error=>"unexpected token at 'H'",
    : level=>: error
}
```

Comment: Did you modify the Elasticsearch index template in the Logstash installation directory (lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json)? There appears to be a spurious "H" at the end of the file.

Comment: No, I haven't modified anything other than what is stated in my question.

Comment: Okay, but _is_ there an "H" at the end of said file? The error message certainly indicates that.

Comment: I just checked the file you mentioned, but there is no H at the end of the file.